Fixing error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry SHAID1
Running git fsck reveals:
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry SHAID1
error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry SHAID1
error: refs/remotes/origin/master: invalid reflog entry SHAID1
broken link from  commit SHAID2
              to  commit SHAID1
missing blob SHAID3
missing commit SHAID1

Trying to implement answers from other related questions, for instance here, I tried git reflog expire --stale-fix --all
This did not seem to work: I obtain:
error: could not read SHAID1
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit SHAID2

SHAID1 and SHAID2 are older commits (I am able to verify that these exist on github.com of my repository.)
git reflog returns:
....    
SHAID2 HEAD@{5}: commit: comment_of_SHAID2
SHAID4 HEAD@{7}: commit: comment_of_SHAID4
....

clearly indicating that HEAD@{6} with SHAID1 is missing.
Is it possible to recover/restore the repository correctly without these errors?

Did you already try to temporarily rename/move your .git/logs/HEAD file (containing said reflog entries)?

Do you need the reflog or this particular reflog entry? If not, just ignore this particular error. Reflogs are not an essential part of a Git repository.

@RomainValeri Yes, just removed that file elsewhere and tried git fsck and the issue still persists.

@j6t Actually, my IDE seems to use this information to display a graphical tree structure.  Currently, the error on opening this graphical display is error: Could not read SHAID1 fatal: revision walk setup failed

@RomainValeri Actually, on opening the said HEAD file, I notice the presence of this very SHAID1 listed along with its parent/child. I also notice that this particular commit has a really long commit message -- the longest of all commit messages. Do you think that could be the reason? Can I for instance, go ahead and reduce the length of the commit message in this file to see if that has an impact?

@Tryer No idea :-) Make a backup and retry using a shortened version indeed.

@RomainValeri Yes, tried it :-) did not work. Still error persists. It is a tooth ache for sure. However, I am able to see on github.com all my remote commits including SHAID1. So, I will just work from there I guess :-) thanks for your suggestions.

I am not sure it is not a git problem/corruption I certainly hope it is not a git problem. isnt it problematic that git fsck returns an error with the HEAD file and without? Is there for instance, a way to regenerate the HEAD file so that git fsck and git reflog do not return errors?

There are plenty of tips how you can salvage a missing object from another repository that still has it.

Well, here is what seems to work for me in the sense that git fsck and git log do not give an error. I cloned git clone http//repository.git  into a new folder. Then, removed the local .git folder of the local repo and replaced it with the one in the cloned folder. Voila! atleast the git fsck and git log no longer produce an error. Not sure what the takeaway from this is....but just wanted to close the loop. On doing so, there seem to be a large number of uncomiitteed changes. I will have to figure out how to deal with them! Thanks.
